# php проблема с SQL-запросом

Tags: php, sql

формирую вот такой SQL запрос:

```
$race = 1;    
$_SESSION['login'] = 'Inkognitoo92';

$query  = "INSERT INTO users ( users_race ) VALUES ( $race ) WHERE users_login_name = '$_SESSION[login]'";    
mysql_query( $query ) or die ( mysql_error() );
```

Получаю в ответ сообщение вот такого вида:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'WHERE
>   users_login_name = Inkognitoo92' at
>   line 1

Что не так с синтаксисом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оформите его как следует:

```
$query  = "INSERT INTO `users` SET `users_race` = '".$race."'";
```

Comment: У Вас как-то странно кавычки расставлены...
Сделал вот так:
$query  = "INSERT INTO users ( 'users_race' ) VALUES ( '$race' ) WHERE 'users_login_name' = '".$_SESSION['login']."' ";

Теперь имею:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''users_race' ) VALUES ( '1' ) WHERE 'users_login_name' = 'Inkognitoo92'' at line 1

Comment: А мой пример не работает?

Comment: Ваш выдаёт:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING
 
Если немного поправлю синтаксис:
$query  = "INSERT INTO `users` ('"."users_race"."') VALUES ('".$race."') WHERE `users_login_name` = '".$_SESSION[login]."'";

То:
Notice: Use of undefined constant login - assumed 'login' in /home/inkognitoo/www/choice/data_checking.php on line 32 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''users_race') VALUES ('1') WHERE `users_login_name` = 'Inkognitoo92'' at line 1

Comment: Подправил, пробуйте

Comment: Всё так же...

Notice: Use of undefined constant login - assumed 'login' in /home/inkognitoo/www/choice/data_checking.php on line 33 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `users_login_name` = 'Inkognitoo'' at line 1

Comment: Странно, где оно увидело вывод константы... Пробуйте такой вариант

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `users_login_name` = 'Inkognitoo'' at line 1

Comment: Стоп, а какой Where может быть при добавление?? В этом и беда, т.к фильтровка идет при select, update, delete ...

Answer (score 3):

rtfm [Синтаксис оператора INSERT](http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/insert.html).
Для `insert` нету `where`. В переводе на русский вы хотите вставить новую запись такую, что `users_login_name` равен чему-то - nonsence in basic :). У вас получилась смесь `insert into` и `insert ... select`, а хотелось видимо `insert ... on duplicate`, да? Тогда так:

```
INSERT INTO users ( users_race, users_login_name ) 
VALUES ( $race, '$_SESSION[login]' )
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE users_race=$race
```

При этом должен присутствовать unique индекс по users_login_name.

Или возможен вариант, что вам нужен не `insert`, а просто `update`. Тогда так:

```
UPDATE users
SET users_race = $race
WHERE
  users_login_name = '$_SESSION[login]'
```

ЗЫ Формулируйте задачу четче. Без понимания что вы хотите сделать приходится догадываться.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, что кавычек не хватает. В итоге должно получиться так:

users_login_name = 'Inkognitoo92'

Comment: В примере там есть вроде кавычка( в коде)))

Comment: Приглядитесь:
'WHERE users_login_name = 'Inkognitoo92'' at line 1

Inkognitoo92 окружен кавычками, но это не отменяет ошибки...

Comment: @Inkognitoo 
Теперь приглядитесь вы в текст сообщения об ошибке: 
 'WHERE users_login_name = Inkognitoo92'

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так

$race = 1;  
$_SESSION['login'] = 'Inkognitoo92';

$query  = "INSERT INTO users ( users_race ) VALUES ( $race ) WHERE users_login_name = '{$_SESSION['login']}'";  
mysql_query( $query ) or die ( mysql_error() );